# What is enforceable on this patent?

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-lifetime, us5584962

For patent # 5,584,962 I have developed a tensioned hub for the supply roll that fits these machines.  This mainly concerns figure 8.  My hub design is different.

My questions are:

1. How can I tell what is patented in 5,586,962.  Is the tensioned function patented?  Is the hub design?
2. Also, when would this patent expire?

Answer (score 1):

As with all patents, it is the claims that define what the inventor "owns". In both independent claims there are elements a - h. *All* of the eight elements must be present for something to infringe.

It looks like this would have expired 17 years from issue which was Dec. of 2013.

Comment: Why would this patent expire in Dec. of 2013 and not May of 2014?

Comment: Now patent term is 20 years from filing. For applications filed before June 1995 it was 17 years from issue. I hope I did the math right.